# ASP.NET: Is there any navigation related to the year property in the Calendar web control?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I'd like to use an ASP.NET **Calendar** web control. So far, to go from the default year (2011) to a different one, I need to use the month navigation arrows. That's really hard when the user need to submit his date of birth.

Is there any navigation related to the year in the Calendar web control?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You could easily use a client side Calendar, like jQuery Date Picker which provides much more interactivity to the end user. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ OR the one is Ajax Toolkit.

Comment: I've just checked the Jquery datepicker. It does not allow the year navigation either.

Comment: jQuery Date Picker surely supports year navigation. I think you missed the other examples (to your right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: https://web.archive.org/web/20210304123649/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090104-1.aspx

Comment: That's an interesting solution. But, Scott Mitchell does not use a Calendar, bur rather 2 dropdownlists. In fact I saw a calendar control on my university website where it's possible to click the year, then a listbox would appears with as many dates as the user want. But, I like also what you've just proposed me. Thanks

Comment: I usually don't recommend this ... but ... in case you want to ... try the ajax toolkit calendar: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was able to get to distant dates. Just being curious, so Why you do not recommend this?

Comment: the toolkit is ... glitchy ... gives devs nightmares when not working correctly ... and sometimes breaks other things in its way :( but when it works correctly, it's pretty cool :)

Comment: Usually, the general advice, is to use jquery - so, just keep that in mind when considering the toolkit for other things which jquery may already have implemented.

Comment: If advise ti use JQuery, then I'll use it instead of ASP.NET toolkit. I've just checked the JQuery datepicker, but It doesn't comport the faculty to access distant years in just few clicks. Unless there are options in JQuery datepicker that I need to customize... But, as I said, getting to distant dates is a nightmare with the regular calendar

Comment: Lol, misspelled advise :P  try this jquery plugin: http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Comment: I looked carefully the official JQuery Datepicker, I believe there's a way of customizing it to obtain the functionality. Thanks also for the new link you've just provided me.

Comment: No problem; that is actually the nice thing about jquery - easy to understand and to customize (and its cross-browser compatible - more so than the ajax toolkit)